# meaning of "pass on" in my book

Tags: meaning-in-context

The text is as following.

Ashley writes:

> He (Bruise) pulled out a pair of black sweats, a black shirt, and shoe polish: "I'll rub this on my face, and while I'm down there, you'll be here with the phone."
>   "No way. I'm not letting you have all the fun." He pulled out another pair of black sweat and a black shirt: "I thought you'd say that."

And then there is writing of Bruise about Ashley:

> Ashley passed on the shoe polish - she said she'd risk her face picking up a little light.

Can you explain to me what "to pass on" is meaning here:
1) to take shoe polish and use it;
2) to refuse to use shoe polish.

Comment: *to pass = **to not participate***. Ashley doesn't want to put boot polish on her face, even though this will make her more likely to be seen.

Comment: I am not fully asure, do you mean "she said she'd risk her face picking up a little light" is the same like "she said she wanted to risk her face picking up a little light"?

Answer (score 1):

In this sentence, "passed" means "declined, refused, decided against". Ashley decided not to use the shoe polish.

By the way, you should note that this meaning of the phrase "passed on" requires the word "passed" to be stressed and the word "on" to be unstressed. The word "on" is functioning as a preposition here.

Most meanings of "passed on", on the other hand, require the word "on" to be stressed. I think it's because the word "on" is an adverb in those meanings.

This means that there are sentences that are written the same way, but whose meaning changes depending on the stressed. If you say "I passed on the offer" with the word "passed" stressed and the word "on" unstressed, you're saying that you declined the offer. If you say "I passed on the offer" with the word "on" stressed, you're saying that you forwarded the offer to someone else.